# Can't build JavaScript universal Windows app

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2015

I have started a new project - javascript - windows universal app and without changing anything or adding any code I try to build it and run it but it wont with the following error:

> Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80080204: App manifest validation error: The document root element m:Package must be defined in the http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest namespace. (0x80080204)  App7

A similar issue was reported [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6b10f3e5-94bc-48d6-8366-291200b82bf1/dep0700-registration-of-the-app-windowslicensing-failed-?forum=toolsforwinapps) and I tried renewing the license with project -> store -> aquire developer license  to no avail. It seems to be that the actual problem has to be the document root element part which I'm not really familiar with as I haven't worked with Visual Studio before I tried to add `xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest"` to my package `appxmanifest` but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Heres the whole manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp m">

  <Identity
    Name="155dc546-80c7-4275-b2a6-a2aa8ddec5f7"
    Version="1.0.0.0"
    Publisher="CN=FroboZ" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="155dc546-80c7-4275-b2a6-a2aa8ddec5f7" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>App7</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>FroboZ</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>images\storelogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10069.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10069.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application
      Id="App"
      StartPage="default.html">

      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="App7"
        Description="App7"
        BackgroundColor="#464646"
        Square150x150Logo="images\Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="images\SmallLogo.png">

        <uap:SplashScreen Image="images\splashscreen.png" />

      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>

</Package>
```

Thank you for taking your time to read my question and even more so if you can help me with this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer mode wasn't turned on in windows 10. I'm not sure what difference this makes but after turning this on I was able to build the project.