# Windows Universal App error

Tags: win-universal-app

I created a new Windows Universal App. I get the following error when I run it. What should I do to fix this error?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80080204: App manifest validation error: The document root element m:Package must be defined in the http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest namespace. (0x80080204)   App1
```

Comment: are you building it on windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the same issue mentioned in [Can't build JavaScript universal Windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753903/cant-build-javascript-universal-windows-app)

But I will suggest you make your windows 10 and VS 2015 up to date, since above question was asked about 1 month ago.

Answer (score -1):

To find following steps to solve the Error/problem.

1) Close visual studio and simulator .

2)Then go to My Computer--C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Packages----

where EditBook is your PC Name

3)delete all folder/files included in the Packages folder, try again to  clean and rebuild Solution.

Also find following link for that:-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx